# How to always fetch a special category item data first in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Suppose I have a table named `machine` with 3 columns(`id`, `name`, `company`).

There are 5 data in that table.

```
01, A, XX
02, B, XX
03, C, XY
04, D, XX
05, E, YY
```

Here `A,B,C,D,E` are the `machine name` and `XX,XY,YY` are the `company name`.

Now I want to fetch data according to company wise and there a specific company's data will come always first. For that I use `groupBy` with `company`.

**SQL**

```
select('*')
from('machine')
groupBy('company')
get()
```

**Result**

```
01, A, XX
03, C, XY
05, E, YY
```

But I want to retrieve data where `XX` company's data will always come first like below format

```
    01, A, XX
    02, B, XX
    04, D, XX
    03, C, XY
    05, E, YY
```

How to do that ? Anybody can help please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by whether the company name is `XX` or not, using a boolean condition in [`orderbyRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries):

```
->orderbyRaw("company = 'XX' DESC")
```

If you want to sort multiple companies in order, use a `CASE` expression:

```
->orderbyRaw("CASE company WHEN 'XX' THEN 1
                           WHEN 'XY' THEN 2
                           ELSE 3
              END")
```

Comment: @Nick....absolutely correct. But if I want `XX` data first, `XY` data second and `YY` data last...then what should I do ?